# Getting beginning and ending date in Java

Tags: java

I am writing a program in Java that allows the user to select a choice (1 : New, 2: Print Range, 3: Print All, quit). Once they choose one of the above they then enter the appointment date if they chose "New" and also enter a description for the appointment and lastly they pick if the appointment will be (1 = Once, 2 = Daily, 3 = Monthly).

I am getting an error on the line "**if (list.i.compareTo(lowDate) <= 0) && (list.i.compareTo(highDate) >= 0);**" It is giving me the error "**AppointmentNew.java:69: illegal start of expression**". I am not sure exactly why it is giving me that error!

Here is my code, I believe I have it all completed to carry out the above tasks!

```
import java.util.*;

public class AppointmentNew 
{
public static void main (String[] args)
{
  List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
  Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
  String choice = "";
  int choiceNum = 0;
  String date = "";
  String descrip = "";
  int type = 0;
  String typeChose = "";

  System.out.println("Welcome to Appointment App!\n");
  System.out.println("\t============================\n");

  do
  {
     System.out.print("\tMake Choice ( 1: New, 2: Print Range, 3: Print All, quit): ");
     choice = stdin.nextLine();

     choiceNum = Integer.parseInt(choice);

     if (choiceNum == 1)
     {
        System.out.print("\n\n\tEnter New Appointment Date in mm/dd/yyyy format: ");
        date = stdin.nextLine();

        System.out.print("\n\n\tEnter New Appointment Description: ");
        descrip = stdin.nextLine();

        System.out.print("\n\n\tEnter Type (1 = Once, 2 = Daily, 3 = Monthly): ");
        type = stdin.nextInt();
        if (type == 1)
        {
          Once once = new Once(date, descrip);
           typeChose = "One-Time";
        }
        else if (type == 2)
        {
          Daily daily = new Daily(date, decrip);
           typeChose = "Daily";
        }
        else
        {
          Monthly monthly = new Monthly(date, descrip);
           typeChose = "Monthly";
        }
          String stringToAdd = "";
          strinToAdd = "New " + descrip + " Appointment Added for " + date;
          list.append(stringToAdd);

        System.out.println("\n\n\tNew " + typeChose + " Appointment Added for " + date);

     }

     if (choiceNum == 2)
     {
     System.out.print("\n\n\tEnter START Date in mm/dd/yyyy format: ");
     String lowDate = stdin.nextLine();
     System.out.print("\n\n\tEnter END Date in mm/dd/yyyy format: ");
     String highDate = stdin.nextLine();

     for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
        {
         int dateSpot = list.i.indexOf(" ");
           if (list.i.compareTo(lowDate) <= 0) && (list.i.compareTo(highDate) >= 0);
        {
           System.out.println(list.i);   
       }}
     }

     if (choiceNum == 3)
     {
       for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
       {
          System.out.println(list.i);     
       }
     }

  }while (choice != "quit");
```

}
}

Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of problems.  To access a list item in a `Collection` you would need to use the `get(int)` method...

```
list.get(i)
```

The if statement is formed wrong...

```
if (list.i.compareTo(lowDate) <= 0) && (list.i.compareTo(highDate) >= 0);
                                  ^-- Bad bracket
                                                                        ^-- This shouldn't be here
```

Should be

```
if (list.get(i).compareTo(lowDate) <= 0 && list.get(i).compareTo(highDate) >= 0)
```

Note, you have an extra closing bracket where you don't need it and the `;` at the end of the statement is going to make the statement redundant (ie it won't actually do anything)

Answer (score 1):

The syntax `list.i` for accessing an element of the list is incorrect.  You should use the [`get(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get%28int%29) method, e.g. `list.get(i)`, to get an element of the list.

Additionally, the entire `if` condition must be enclosed its own parentheses, and there shouldn't be a semicolon following between the `if` and the block in braces below it:

```
if ((list.get(i).compareTo(lowDate) <= 0) && (list.get(i).compareTo(highDate) >= 0))
{
    System.out.println(list.get(i));
}
```

There are numerous other errors, including attempting to compare a `String` value with `==` (don't do that, use String's `equals` method), plus brace closing issues.

Comment: Ok, Thank you for that! But it is still giving me the same error after fixing the "list.i" to "list.get(I)"

Comment: Sorry to be so blunt, I am just very frustrated with this, I have been trying to fix this for at least two hours

Comment: The `list.get(i)` thing was the first thing I noticed; I've updated my answer to include a couple more corrections.

Comment: So you're saying for instance in the line "If (choiceNum == 3)" I should instead use "If (choiceNum.equals(3))"?